# Neo4j - encountering FetchURLError whenever using any query with GET or POST

Tags: neo4j, cypher, rdf, property-graph

I am using Neo4j Desktop application and trying a cypher query to export RDF. I am using the default available load-movie.cypher data in local DB as a trial but everytime I run the query it gives **FetchURLError** so I dont know what I am doing wrong.Also to add that all other match queries are working fine. Here is the query that I tried:-

```
:POST /rdf/neo4j/cypher 
{"cypher": 
         "MATCH g = (:Person {name: 'Keanu Reeves'})-->(:Movie { title: 'The Matrix'}) 
          RETURN g", 
 "format" : "RDF/XML"}
```

Then I tried a simple GET query :-

```
:GET /rdf/neo4j/describe/11
```

But the response is always:

```
 FetchURLError - Could not fetch URL: "Failed to fetch".
```

This could be due to the remote server policy. See your web browsers error console for more information.

Need some help in resolving the issue.

Comment: did you install the plugin for RDF support?

Comment: I did and followed all the steps for installation.The query for ping also works but any other query shows FetchURLError

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem and for me it worked by writing the full URL. E.g.:

```
:GET http://localhost:7474/rdf/neo4j/describe/11
```